# How to check if a tag has any text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="Div5" style="width: 85%; margin: 10px auto;">
    <h4 class="hpH4"></h4>
    <p class="hpP setLeft">
        <taMsg></taMsg>
    </p>
    <span class="hideContent" id="Span5">selInf</span>
</div>
```

Query:

```
$("taMsg").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
        alert("THERE IS NO TEXT");
    }
});​
```

The above isn't working. How can I modify so if `taMsg` doesn't have any text, I get an alert.

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/8Lh5f3uq/

Comment: I am using XSLT to generate the HTML. So maybe that is why it can't find it?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - Run this fiddle and observe that there is a space within the `<taMsg>` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/8Lh5f3uq/2/

Comment: @Krishna, sorry, you're right...

Comment: It is [*much more efficient*](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-pojs-no-text) to use `if (!/\S/.test(this.textContent || this.innerText))`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `:empty`:

```
$("taMsg").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
        alert("THERE IS NO TEXT");
    }
});​
```

or you can do something like this to avoid a div with spaces:

```
$("taMsg").each(function(){
    if(!$.trim($(this).html()).length) {
        alert("THERE IS NO TEXT");
    }
});​
```

You can select all empty/not empty elements using the same selector:

```
var emptyList = $("taMsg:empty");
var notEmptyList = $("taMsg:not(:empty)");
```

Comment: A little too fast, as it would seem it contains an error.

Comment: It's also *the* slowest of the options here, 10 times slower than the fastest (which doesn't use jQuery for the test). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must tell us how do you wish to treat white-space? This code is removing white-space:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('taMsg').each(function(index) {
     if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "") {
      console.log('test');
     };
  });

});
```